# MASM -- how to define a procedure with the same name as a keyword?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm

How do I define a procedure cal, for example, `fabs` in MASM?

```
fabs PROC
     ...
fabs END
```

gives me an error, because `fabs` is a built-in instruction name.

Comment: why would you want to do that? add a underscore or something to indicate that is a custom one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find an option for MASM (`/Cp`, `/Cx`, `/Cu` don't seem to help). But I found a workaround for TASM:

```
public fabs

code segment

fabs proc
nop
ret
fabs endp

code ends

end
```

Can be compiled as `tasm.exe /ml fa.asm`. `fabs` will appear in the object file and listing as the symbol name. Listing:

```
Symbol Name                       Type   Value

??date                            Text   "12/04/11"
??filename                        Text   "fa      "
??time                            Text   "04:32:11"
??version                         Number 0314
@Cpu                              Text   0101H
@FileName                         Text   fa
@WordSize                         Text   2
@curseg                           Text   code
fabs                              Near   code:0000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
option nokeyword: <fabs>

.code
fabs proc
    ret
fabs endp
```